# is there analog of unix program "which" in DOS operating system?

Tags: dos

is there analog of unix program which in DOS operating system?

How can I determine location of file of program that I run in DOS operating system, specially in FreeDOS?

Comment: `echo %PATH%` or find file via `dir file.com /s /p`